# Doing accurate floating point division in Python 3

Tags: python, floating-point

Is there a way to do accurate floating point division in Python?

Let's say I try to do the following mathematical operations.

1. `0.6 / 0.3` returns `2.0` which is correct. Cool, it looks like math is working!
2. `0.6 / 0.2` returns `2.9999999999999996` when `3.0` would be the correct result.
3. `0.6 / 0.1` returns `5.999999999999999` when `6.0` would be the correct result.

I'm wondering if there is a simple solution to this issue that I'm totally missing?

Note: I have seen the answers for [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and although many of the answers do an outstanding job of explaining floating point operations, it does not appear that any of the responses provide an actual solution on how to accurately do division with floating point values in Python.

Comment: does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: use `round((0.6 / 0.3),4)` this will do the division with 4 digits precisions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate. Note that if you really need arbitrary precision, you can use the module `decimal`. There is no free lunch -- computations are slower if you go that route.

Comment: Hi @JohnColeman, I think the `decimal` module may provide an optimally accurate solution when calculating these results. Thank you for suggesting it as I did not see it mentioned in any of the top answers to the related question.

Comment: The problem is not that the division is not accurately performed but that decimal fractions you type in cannot be exactly represented in a regular float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) library provides functionality to calculate more accurate results when floating point division would otherwise provide less accurate results.

Here is an example that shows the `decimal` library returning the correct results to a few floating point values being divided.

```
from decimal import Decimal
```

1. `Decimal('0.6') / Decimal('0.3')` returns `Decimal('2')` which is correct.
2. `Decimal('0.6') / Decimal('0.2')` returns `Decimal('3')` which is correct.
3. `Decimal('0.6') / Decimal('0.1')` returns `Decimal('6')` which is correct.

As @JohnColeman noted, using the decimal module for these calculations will provide more accureate results, but at the expense of the speed at which the claculations are executed.